# unformatted i/o to and from memory

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to write unformatted data to memory using the C++ standard library. I'd like a class which inherits istream/ostream and works like ifstream/ofstream, but backed by memory instead of a file on disk.

This way I can work with istreams and ostreams and use operator<< and operator>> to read/write binary data, and I don't need to know whether the data is streaming into memory or onto disk.

I thought perhaps istringstream/ostringstream could be configured to write unformatted output via operator<< and operator>>, but I couldn't see a simple way to do this.

So I wasn't able to find anything like this in the C++ standard library or in boost, but it seems like the sort of thing that should be there. Any advice would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `<<` and `>>` operators to write/read unformatted data (they are dealing only with textual input and output), but you can use the [`write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) method of output streams and the [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) method of input streams.

And as `std::string` actually don't really care about the data it holds you should be able to use `stringstream` (and its output/input variants).

Comment: It didn't look like stringstream would work since it always wants to format numbers as strings, e.g. 173 shows up as "173" not as 0xAD.